# PowerShell. Вывод суммарного времени пингования компьютера

Tags: windows, powershell

Как можно в PowerShell написать сценарий, выводящий суммарное время пингования компьютера (например 192.168.10.10) в сети.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Но зачем изобратеть велосипед?

```
[int]$t = $null
(Test-Connection 192.168.10.10).ResponseTime | foreach {
    $t += $_
}

Write-Host "Ping time: $t ms"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param (
[Parameter (Mandatory=$true, helpmessage="host or IP")]
[string]$in_host,

[Parameter (Mandatory=$true)]
[int]$count)

$rt=0
for($i=0;$i -lt $count;$i++)
{
$info=Get-WmiObject -Class win32_pingstatus -f "Address='$in_host'"  
write-host "Адрес:" $in_host "Время:" $info.responsetime "ms" "Статус" $info.StatusCode "Время жизни" $info.TimeToLive
$rt+=$info.ResponseTime


}
Write-Host "Время пингования:" $rt "ms"
```